# problems when adding a class to my C# application

Tags: c#, class, object

I'm trying to create a object that generates words as a label component and display them in the screen when the button is clicked.

If I place the code right inside the event `BtnStart_Click`, it works fine, but when i try to create a class `WordGenerator` with the same code it wont work.

If I go with the mouse over the `"words[0] = new ...."` in the class `WordGenerator` it gives msgbox saying "The name 'words' does not exist in the current context.".
I dont understand why is that. When in the previous line i declare 'words' being an array of label.

[image: follow a picture to illustrate my problem]

Comment: You need to put it in a method, you can't have statements like this just in the class body

Comment: Please check [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+how+to+write+a+class&rlz=1C1CHZL_enLB749LB749&oq=c%23+how+to+write+a+class&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j0l4.4257j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do like that, make use of constructor for initializing member variables like the following:

```
public WordGenerator()
{
   this.words[0] = new Label();
   // rest of initializations here
}
```

Or else you can use a method to complete the initialization:

```
public void InitializeWords()
{
   this.words[0] = new Label();
   // rest of initializations here
}
```